# What does void pointer with 'this' means?

Tags: c++, pointers, void

In c++, what does 'this' mean?

I found that it doesn't use 'this', but use like this.
"(void*) this"

Is it similar to 'this' in Java?

Comment: There are really two separate questions: (1) what does `this` mean, and (2) what does `void*` mean.

Comment: "this" means exactly the same thing in Java as in C++: it refers to "your own class instance".  "void*" means "a pointer to anything"; casting to "(void *)" means that it's no longer a pointer to your specific class type.

Comment: No, you didn't find that out at all. You found some strange code that does that, probably unnecessarily. `void *` casts in C++ are usually a sign of not quite knowing what you're doing.

Answer (score 3):

`this` is a pointer in C++. It serves a similar functionality to "this" in Java only that it is must be dereferenced when accessing a data member. `(*this).x` would refer to the data member called x. `this->x` achieves the same purpose with syntactic sugar.

void * is the generic type for a pointer. The use in your question is casting the type of this  which is a pointer of your object type into one that is generic. It is standard pointer conversion.